# Mysql : get data from perticular date and time

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables daypart,schedule, schedule_daypart. Data in the tables as follows,
Daypart table have 4 entries

```
id | start_time | end_time  
 1 | 09:00:01 | 12:00:00  
 2 | 12:00:01 | 18:00:00  
 3 | 18:00:01 | 23:59:59  
 4 | 00:00:01 | 09:00:00


Schedule table  
id | start_date | end_date  
 1 | 10-Sept-2013 | 12-Sept-2013  
 2 | 10-Sept-2013 | 15-Sept-2013   


schedule_daypart  
id | schedule_id | daypart_id  
1 | 1 | 1  
2 | 1 | 2  
3 | 1 | 3  
4 | 1 | 4  
5 | 2 | 1  
6 | 2 | 2  
7 | 2 | 3
```

Now i want to write stored procedure which will take date and time parameters and gives the schedule_id and daypart_id. e.g. if i provide date as 11-Sett-2013 and time as 13:30:00 then output will be

```
schedule_id | daypart_id  
 1 | 2  
 1 | 3  
 1 | 4  
 2 | 2  
 2 | 3
```

Comment: have you tried..? drream never come true unless you try...

Comment: try joining the tables and comparing the relevant values ^^

Comment: i have tried,, but it take 3 parameters date, time and daypart_id. But i don't want daypart_id to provide as parameter. And if i provide daypart_id then time has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    JT.schedule_id, JT.daypart_id
FROM schedule_daypart JT
INNER JOIN daypart DP ON JT.daypart_id = DP.id
INNER JOIN Schedule S ON JT.schedule_id = S.id
WHERE S.start_date <= STR_TO_DATE('2013, 11 09', '%Y, %d %m') AND S.end_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2013, 11 09', '%Y, %d %m') AND DP.start_time >= STR_TO_DATE('13:30:00','%h:%i:%s') AND DP.end_time <= STR_TO_DATE('13:30:00','%h:%i:%s')
```

Updated:

```
STR_TO_DATE('13:30:00','%h:%i:%s')
```

Comment: query is not working. daypart table don't have start_date and end_date column, and if i change the query, not working

Comment: Updated the query, small mistake it was i think you should make some effort on it, its very easy error to solve. nyways updated it please have a look nw..

Comment: @Vishal  This should work if you have date datatype for start and end date and time datatype for start and end time.

Comment: @AbhishekJain if i run only select STR_TO_DATE('13:30:00','a%h:%i:%s') it gives null output.